# Why use a completer when you can return a async callback function?

Tags: dart

Is there any benefit in using completers when you can return an asynchronous callback function(which will return a future).

Example:

```
Future function() {
   return this.socket.request(successCallBack: (response) {
       .......
       return true;
    }); // async call.
```

against

```
   Future function() {
       Completer c = new Completer();
       this.socket.request( .. (...){// async callback.
           c.complete(xyz);
        }); 
        return c.future;
   }
```

Here, The futures return xyz value in both instances. Is it a style preference?

Comment: I don't know anything about dart but I would definitely use the first solution. The second one looks ugly. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A completer is for more complex scenarios, for example when you want to complete a future in another method than where you create it. In your example the completer is redundant.

```
class MyComponent {
  Completer _initDoneCompleter;

  MyComponent() {
    Completer _initDoneCompleter = new Completer();
    someStream.listen(_eventHandler);
  }

  void _eventHandler(e) {
    if(e.someProperty == 'someValue') {
      _initDoneCompleter.complete(e.someProperty);
    }
  }

  static Future<MyComponent> createNew() async {
    var c = new MyComponent();
    await c.initDoneCompleter.future;
    return c;
  }
}

void main() async {
  var c = await MyComponent.createNew();
}
```

Comment: I did not know you can do that. That is awesome! Thanks.